# Comparing MotionEvent.getX() with screen width in Android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent, ontouch, display

I've created an `OnTouchListener` for motion events in an activity, and I want to find where they happen relative to the screen.

I can use `event.getRawX()` to find the x co-ordinate, and similarly `windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(new DisplayMetrics())` or `...getSize(new Point())` to get the display dimensions.

The problem I'm having is that the display dimensions are consistently reporting the width as 1080, but the motionevents I receive return numbers greater than 1800 for `getRawX()`.

Using the deprecated `display.getWidth()` returns something close, around 1700 - but even this is lower than what's reported at the right edge of the screen.

I assume motion events use a different co-ordinate system to the display metrics - but how can I convert between the two?

Cheers

Nic

Comment: Did you mean "... I receive return numbers greater than *1080* for ..." ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have an answer. This is down to my own stupidity.

What I forgot to mention is that I am viewing the screen in landscape mode. Using `v.getWidth()`, rather than the display dimension, returns 1920, which makes much more sense.

So obviously (with hindsight) the view width takes into account the orientation, which the display width doesn't - so I've been reading the portrait width (1080) rather than the landscape width/portrait height (1920).

Goodness knows what `display.getWidth()` was returning...

Thanks to anyone who read and thought about this, and Mihriban for reformatting it.